# Cannot get countDocuments to work Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to return the number of items on a shopping list. The list itself and CRUD works well, but I cannot get the API to return the total number of items in the Collection.

Here's my setup:

```
/_helpers/db.js

/* database config (Mongo Atlas)
```

```
/shopping/shopping.controller.js

const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

...

const shoppingService = require("./shopping.service");

// routes
router.get("/", authorize(), getAll, getNumberOfItems);
router.get("/:id", authorize(), getById);
router.post("/", authorize(), createSchema, create);
router.put("/:id", authorize(), updateSchema, update);
router.delete("/:id", authorize(), _delete);

module.exports = router;

...

function getNumberOfItems(req, res) {
  shoppingService.getNumberOfItems().then((result) => {
    res.json(result);
  });
}

...
```

```
/shopping/shopping.model.js

/* schema for shopping items
```

```
/shopping/shopping.service.js

const config = require("config.json");

...

const db = require("_helpers/db");

module.exports = {
  getAll,
  getById,
  getNumberOfItems,
  create,
  update,
  delete: _delete,
};

...

async function getAll() {
  const items = await db.Shopping.find();
  return items.map((x) => basicDetails(x));
}

...

async function getNumberOfItems() {
  return db.Shopping.countDocuments();
}

...
```

```
server.js

/* The server
```

When I use Postman to create/read/update/delete the API works fine. When I try and access the number of Documents in the Collection nothing is returns. I have checked the method dozens of times against the information found by Googling, but I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Can somebody see where I am going wrong?

Comment: Isn't `res` out of scope at that point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `res` in the `getNumberOfItems` instead of simply returning number of items.

It should look like this

```
async function getNumberOfItems() {
  return db.Shopping.countDocuments();
}
```

and use it like this:

```
function getNumberOfItems(req, res) {
  shoppingService.getNumberOfItems().then(result => {
    res.json(result)
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So I've replaced my code with your fix up, but somehow Postman still doesn't receive a result for number of items. I really can't see why it wouldn't just receive a json response? GET / just returns the items on the list and ignores the getNumberOfItems function

Comment: So if you set a breakpoint at the line `res.json(result)` what will you see in result?

Comment: The same thing. It just returns the items from the getAll and ignores getNumberOfItems

Comment: You don't pass and don't call `next` in `getAll`, that's why your next middleware `getNumberOfItems` is not called

Comment: I haven't pasted all of the content from shopping.controller.js but the `getAll` function does have `next` called: `function getAll(req, res, next) {shoppingService.getAll().then((items) => res.json(items)).catch(next);}`

Comment: But you don't call `next` in case of normal flow after res.json(items)

Comment: Adding `next()` doesn't seem to make any difference? `function getAll(req, res, next) { shoppingService.getAll().then((items) => res.json(items)).next().catch(next);}`

Comment: function getAll(req, res, next) { shoppingService.getAll().then((items) => { res.json(items); next(); }).catch(next);}

Comment: I've updated the code but same problem. Baffling. `GET /` still just returns JSON for each item and nothing for the number of documents.

Comment: I suppose you should not call res.json in getAll if you wish to get a result from getNumberOfItems

Comment: Does that mean it isn't possible to get the number of items and the items on the same route?

Comment: In this case you should place both method calls in the same handler

Comment: It still doesn't work in the same handler: `function getAll(req, res, next) {shoppingService.getAll().then((items) => {res.json(items);}).catch(next); shoppingService.getNumberOfItems().then((result) => {res.json(result); });}`

Comment: You can't return TWO results from one handler. Just pack them both into one object and pass it to `res.json`

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your help and patience!